# Desire2Learn: Maximum length of ShortTitle parameter in creation of link topic

Tags: desire2learn

In the Desire2Learn Valence API, when making a call to the endpoint

`/d2l/api/le/[LE API VERSION]/[ORG UNIT ID]/content/modules/[PARENT MODULE ID]/structure/`

to create a link topic, there is a ShortTitle parameter, which determines how the item will appear in the D2L gradebook.

There seems to be a maximum length for this parameter, resulting in many items that share initial text to appear identically (and thus unhelpfully) in the gradebook.  What is that maximum length and can it be configured?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an upstream limit, but at the database layer the content ShortTitle field is limited to length 50.  (As this is a schema item the upper bound would not be configurable)